# Subreport does not show up when the main report parameter is part of LIKE operator

Tags: reporting-services, sql-like, subreport

I have main report where customer enters either a full serial number or the last 5 characters of the serial number.  The report returns several pieces of information about the product, as well as runs a subreport that gathers additional information.

The main report dataset query is something like this...

```
select SerialNumber, ID, Property1
from Products
where (SerialNumber = @prmSerialNumber) OR (SerialNumber LKE '%' + @prmSerialNumber)
```

When I enter the full serial number "123456789" the result set below is returned:

SerialNumber------------ID-------------Property1

123456789-----------e45f6789---------Green

When I enter the last 5 characters "56789" the exact same result set is returned.  So I know the main dataset is returning the appropriate results, and only a single row.

The subreport dataset query is something like this...

```
select ID, Property2, Property3
from PropertyTable1
where ID = @prmID
```

When I insert the subreport into the main report, on the Subreport Properties, Parameters tab I have linked the subreport parameter @prmID to the main report dataset ID column (prmID = [ID])

When I run the main report, if I enter the full serial number '123456789' the subreport returns the appropriate data.  When I run the main report using the last 5 characters of the serial number, the subreport does not show up at all.

I've tried running the subreport on it's own making the parameter visible and entering the ID from the main report's result set and it runs fine.

I've tried including the serial number in the subreport dataset and using that as the parameter like this...

**UPDATED SUBREPORT QUERY**

```
select p1.ID, p1.Property2, p1.Property3, p2.SerialNumber
from PropertyTable1 AS p INNER JOIN
     Products AS p2 ON p1.ID = p1.ID
where (p2.SerialNumber = @prmSerialNumber) OR (p2.SerialNumber LKE '%' + @prmSerialNumber)
```

When I change the subreport query as above and then run the subreport on it's own, I can use either the full serial number or just the last 5 characters as my parameter value and the report returns the appropriate data either way.  When I add it to my main report though, and update the parameter that gets passed to be @prmSerialNumber = [SerialNumber] (serialnumber from main dataset), it works as long as I enter the full serial number.  As soon as I enter just the last 5 characters, the subreport does not show up.

I also tried updating the parameter that gets passed to be @prmSerialNumber = [@prmSerialNumber] (the parameter entered by the user in the main report).  Same results.  When the full serial number is entered, it works fine.  When the last 5 characters are entered, the subreport does not show up even though it works fine when I run the subreport on its own.

Can't figure out why my subreport will run fine when I run it on it's own and manually enter the parameter value, but as soon as I link it to my main report, it only works if the full serial number is used as the main report parameter value.

Comment: If you are doing this in Visual Studio, then the most common reason is caching. Open the project folder and delete all the *.rdl.data files. This is the sledgehammer approach bit if it works then great. Usually you can just hit the refresh button on the report control toolbar and it will (usually) do the same.

Comment: Tried that already. It's not a cached data issue.